# Как можно составить такое дерево, чтобы оно не смещалось при изменении размера окна?

Tags: css

[alt text http://www.pixelzeesh.com/themes/fusion/layouts/home-video.html](http://www.pixelzeesh.com/themes/fusion/layouts/home-video.html)

Пробовал с :after, но тогда происходит смещение и искривление. Кто может помочь с советом?
[Вот как тут хочу. Прокрутите вниз](http://www.pixelzeesh.com/themes/fusion/layouts/home-video.html)

[image: Хочу избежать вот таких разрывов]

Comment: Выложите код того, что уже сами сделали. Например, на jsFiddle или на  CodePen.  
А вообще, задайте блоку-обертке значение **min-width**.

Comment: как то так http://jsfiddle.net/Jcyn8/1/ . Но я столько изменений делал, что запутался сам =/ Бутстрап подключить не смог туда